# Convert Object to Dictionary with Dot notation

Tags: c#, dictionary

Please find the attach fiddle for the problem [Link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uBsWxA)

What I would like to do is convert an object to an Dictionary
The object looks like this

```
var person = new Person
{
    FirstName = "Jon",
    LastName = "Doe",
    Address = new Address
    {
        Street = "Melkbos",
        PostalCode = 90210
    }
};
```

And the desired output should look like this

```
{
 {"FirstName", "Jon"},
 {"LastName", "Doe"},
 {"Address.Street", "Melkbos"},
 {"Address.PostalCode", 90210},
};
```

So if the object is nested i want to have an dot notation

Comment: Are you asking if there's some built im method that can do this automatically?

Comment: Is reflection an option?

Comment: @glenebob, if there is an built in way that would be great, but i don't think there is, hence the extension method.

Comment: @smoksnes, reflection is an option yes.

Comment: I must be missing something here... But it looks like you just need to write a line of code for each property, such as "new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Address.Street", obj.Address.Street)".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use recursion and test for the type of the property you want to serialize. I modified part of your code to do this, using `IsSerializable`. You may need to tweak this to suit your exact needs:

```
public static IDictionary<string, T> ToDictionary<T>(this object source)
{
    if (source == null)
        ThrowExceptionWhenSourceArgumentIsNull();

    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, T>();
    AddPropertiesToDictionary(new List<string>(), source, dictionary);
    return dictionary;
}

private static void AddPropertiesToDictionary<T>(IList<string> path, object source, IDictionary<string, T> dictionary)
{
    foreach (PropertyDescriptor property in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(source))
    {
        var value = property.GetValue(source);
        if (IsOfType<T>(value))
        {
            if (property.PropertyType.IsSerializable) {
                dictionary.Add((path.Any() ? string.Join(".", path) + "." : "") + property.Name, (T)value);
            }
            else
            {
                path.Add(property.Name);
                AddPropertiesToDictionary(path, value, dictionary);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Key                Value
FirstName          Jon  
LastName           Doe  
Address.Street     Melkbos 
Address.PostalCode 90210
```

You should be able to modify this get your curly braces and quotes in there pretty easily.

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thanks a ton, Jon!

Answer (score -1):

I think reflection is not necessary since you know properties names, you could try this:

```
namespace personToDictionary
{
    public class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public Address Address { get; set; }

        public Dictionary<string, string> ToDictionary()
        {
            return new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"FirstName", FirstName},
                {"LastName", LastName},
                {"Address.Street", Address.Street},
                {"Adress.PostalCode", Address.PostalCode.ToString()}
            };
        } 
    }

    public class Address
    {
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public int PostalCode { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var person = new Person
            {
                FirstName = "Jon",
                LastName = "Doe",
                Address = new Address
                {
                    Street = "Melkbos",
                    PostalCode = 90210
                }
            };
            var personDictionary = person.ToDictionary();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Instead of "FirstName" you could use nameof(FirstName) - assuming you are up on c# 6